tabulator.js: rownum starting with 0
is there any way to start with 0 (instead of 1) when using the "rownum"-formatter under tabulator.js?
Version: 6.2
{title:"auto", field:"auto", width:10, headerSort:false, formatter:"rownum"}


You could use a custom formatter to achieve this:
{title:"auto", field:"auto", width:10, headerSort:false, formatter:function(row){
    return row.getPosition() - 1; //adjust the row position to 0 index it
}}

